# What is the simplest way to increase volume of mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

This hand looks too skinny. What is the simplest way to make it fatter, especially the fingers?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Edit Mode, you can use the Shrink/Fatten tool. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
It is limited to the selection.

[image]

---

You can also add a displacement modifier and change the strength value.
For more control assign a vertex group to it. Create a the group and go into weight paint mode <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to paint the weights.

[image]
<sup>*It seems the gif progress bar got messed up. Sorry.*</sup>